# URL mapping is not working in web.xml in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

1. Package name controller where WelcomeController is there
2. folder view in WEB-INF where view files are there means html and static jsp
3. In view welcome.jsp
4. In WebContent web.xml and welcome-servlet.xml are there

When I mapped **/** but when I changed the url-pattern then it's not working e.g. /user/* following url is working for only /

> http://localhost:3000/SpringPractice/user/welcome

Error is

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/SpringPractice/user/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'welcome'

it's working if I set the  to /.
Even I checked the controller no error because if no mapping is found then it'd not work for / pattern.

**WEB.XML**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**WelcomeController.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/user/welcome")
    public String GET(ModelMap model){
        //second is the message name
        //3rd is the message
        model.addAttribute("message","GET Method");
        return "welcome";       //we'll always return the name of the view here welcome.jsp e.g. welcome
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/user/welcome")
    public String POST(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message","POST Method");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**welcome-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: It’s about DispatcherServlet slurping part of the matched path. Try RequestMapping with only ”welcome” value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211981/5032692

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml needs to be modified if you want the servlet to map to SpringPractice as the root

**Change your web.xml to look like this:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SpringPractice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It's also possible you are using the wrong port. Tomcat (Which I am assuming you are using here) uses port **8080** by default.

The URL: http://localhost:8080/SpringPractice/user/welcome

Should now work just fine

---

**The following is not needed, is just might be helpful**

Also, you can use `@RequestMapping` on the class level if you wish.

```
@Controller
@RequstMapping(value="/user/welcome")
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="")
    public String GET(ModelMap model){
        //second is the message name
        //3rd is the message
        model.addAttribute("message","GET Method");
        return "welcome";       //we'll always return the name of the view here welcome.jsp e.g. welcome
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="")
    public String POST(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message","POST Method");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

By adding `RequestMapping(value="/user/welcome")` to the top of your controller class all the mappings under it will use that as a base. It's nice if you know a certain controller will be handeling all requests from "www.MyCoolSite.com/user/welcome"

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something incorrect in this answer? I would prefer to know so that I can correct it.